# Secure way of creating SQL Database based on user input in C# app

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, programmatically-created

I am struggling to find the solution myself on the Internet.

I have recently learnt that @parameters cannot be used to represent Database Names.

In my case each user should depend on the designated database(for numerous reasons). I thought of creating the database using sqlCommand that combines sql command and input string dynamically but was told that is a silly idea(I agree).

I've heard of SMO, although not sure if this will put me into the right place.

Maybe there is a way of generating random name for database when prompted by user, and then store that name in 'master' database's table along with username for identification purposes?

Until I find the right solution I'm pretty much put on hold with work.

Comment: smo is the way to go

Comment: The DB  name generally belongs in the connection, not the query/commands.  Sounds like your whole design is wrong though.

Comment: I simply use CREATE DATABASE and execute the command. whats wrong with tht?

Comment: You can create a SqlConnection connecting to your "master" database of whather database you have already. Then run your CREATE DATABASE script, after that you can create a SqlConnection on the fly pointing to that recent created database.

Comment: Why does each user have their own database?

Comment: yes, but the original idea was create db name based on user input. that is not a good idea as combining script with the user input invites for malicious code input.

Comment: It is hard to comprehend a situation where you need one DB per user. This "problem" is probably a design issue.  That would also explain why you cannot find an answer on the entire internet. If you really do, then by all means use SMO.

Comment: the structure is the same(Tables, columns etxc). Only data inserted changes. I am still on initial phase of sql part. I can still make a decision. But, since I already use SQLite for each user's client app, it is for me less messy merging the SQLite data with SQL. That is probably the main reason why I opted for designated database for each user. And then, if one user is down, it does not have to affect all the others. Also having shared database exposes other users' data. These are just the ones more important I think.

Comment: @positiveperspective I'm not suggesting that you concatenate strings to form the script you can create proc by all means. I have to tell you that's a weird requirement though

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, I will consider changing the architecture.

Comment: having 1 database for each user.. I couldn't think of a worst archtecture

Comment: that was the suggestion from other stackoverflow user.

Comment: So, each user will have a local SQLite database and you have a central Microsoft SQL Server that you want to sync it up to? Is that what we are talking about here?

Comment: anyway, seeing all this effort to only create users database, and looking at all your comments makes me think that the right thing to do should be identify each row with user id. correct?

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean yes. that was the idea. But I think adding user id to each record shouldn't be the problem. this way I can sync too.

Comment: I think that would be a better design. If you have them all have their own databases you'll run into massive headaches trying to query the data.

Comment: yeah. I think so. I don't really know I ever thought of having designated db for each user. Decison made: I will change the design.

Comment: since we are already here I will ask you one more thing. Should I alter my SQLite tables so there will already be userID or can I leave it as it is and then add userID to each record when doing the transfer of data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I built an app that did something similar to this and what I did was kept a blank database on the SQL Server and made a stored procedure to copy it (with a different name of course).

There are plenty of use cases for single database per user despite what the trolls say.

Answer (score 0):

Well, one way I can think of off the top of my head is to create the database with a stored procedure. You can pass the user input to the SPROC and verify the input there either through parameters in sp_executesql or with QUOTENAME.

Comment: I appreciate your answers. They at least give me some self-confidence in what I was doing so far(the general idea of keeping users data separe). However I decided to change the architecture and I will store all users data together and then identify records by users'id. The data is not very sensitive, so I don't see much of the problem even in case of leak.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike others who commented I can see a use case of DB per user, especially if each customer (company) is a user and you want to separate the data.

The idea that comes to my mind, based on your comment that all databases are the same architecture, is to use the Model database.  Structure that in the manner you want.  Then you can have an SP to create database with a generated name, maybe the user name or other static property to somehow avoid using direct user input (injection...)